# Android: Saved Thumbnail should not appear in gallery

Tags: java, android, gallery

I'm creating a thumbnail from an image. The gallery find the image and list it but I don't want that.

Comment: I retract what I said, I guess it was a proper question with a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the folder you're storting the image also create a file called ".nomedia". This will prevent the gallery from showing all images in that folder.

If you dont want the whole folder to be excluded. You could prefix the image name with a dot. Example: ".myimagethumb" this wil prevent the gallery from showing your file.